# Login authentication

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have placed 2 controller login and site1.When i login and enter to members area to view pages  and if i copy that url and placed in another tab.it opens.But my aim is to display u have no permission to access the page.

Controller:login

```
<?php

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';

        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);    

    }
    function inactive()
    {
    echo"<script>alert('In active user Please contact the administrator');</script>";
    $this->load->view('login_form'); 
    }
    function invalid()
    {
    echo"<script>alert('Invalid username or password');</script>";
    $this->load->view('login_form'); 
    }
    function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

        if($query) // if the user's credentials validated...
        {
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            if($query->num_rows()>0){
             $status = $query->row()->account_status;}
            else {
             $status = ''; }
             //Account active
            if($status == 'active')
            {
               $this->session->set_userdata($data);
               redirect('site1/members_area');
            }
            else  if ($status == 'inactive')//Account In active
            {  $this->inactive();
              }
              else // incorrect username or password
        {
            $this->invalid();
        }
        }

    }   

    function signup()
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'signup_form';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
    }

    function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('college_name', 'college_name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
         $this->load->helper('date');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('signup_form');
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('membership_model');

            if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');           
            }
        }

    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

        $this->index();


    }
```

site1:

```
<?php

class Site1 extends CI_Controller 
{


    function members_area()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');


    }

    function another_page() // just for sample
    {
        echo 'good. you\'re logged in.';
    }

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        {
            echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page. <a href="../login">Login</a>';    
            die();      
            //$this->load->view('login_form');
        }       
    }   

}


    }
```

Comment: r u using the same browser with diff tab?

Comment: Yes I am using same browser

Comment: try use diff browser.. i.e 1 use chrome and another 1 use IE or Firefox..  refer @RobinAbony answer for the explaination..

Answer (score 1):

Sessions in PHP are carried over between tabs. The server doesn't really know how to seperate between two tabs. Read the PHP docs on sessions for more information `http://us2.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php`